How to add mysql database to azure app service backups using managed identities
I have a wordpress app service setup in azure and it applies automatic backups every hour. However, this does not include a database backup so when you go to custom backup you can choose advance and add a connection string for the database backup. However, my application is using managed identities for database connection to the flexible mysql database. So I am curious how can I add a connection string that encompoasses the managed identity for the connection if it is even possible.

Can you share the code if tried any!

Hi I am not sure there is any code as its done through the azure portal. When I am back at my pc i will add the connection string that uses a hardcoded mysql username and pass but ultimately I want to use microsoft entra identity.
